# Apply function returning NULL

Tags: r, apply

I am trying to find skewness of my numeric columns in a data frame. The apply function used in the below code is returning `NULL`. However, when I use the function directly to any of the column it returns values.

```
library(mlbench)
data(Glass)
funNum= function(x){
  if(is.numeric(x)){return(skewness(x))
  }
}

funNum(Glass$Na)
# [1] 0.4478343

apply(Glass,2,funNum)
# NULL
```

Please suggest what is wrong in the above code. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What does `apply(a,2,is.numeric)` give you?

Comment: `apply(a,2,is.numeric)
   RI    Na    Mg    Al    Si     K    Ca    Ba    Fe  Type 
FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE `

Comment: Please provide a [minimal](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [reproducible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) example. After skimming at least one of those links, please provide sample data and code used (such as `skewness`). Please edit your question for this instead of adding comments, thanks!

Comment: @ZheyuanLi - I just applied sapply , it gives the result. However ,i would also like to understand the reason for apply not working here .any probable explanation?

Comment: I have edited the code in the question to make it reproducible .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, my guess in the comment is right: **you have factors!**

```
sapply(Glass, class)
#       RI        Na        Mg        Al        Si         K        Ca        Ba 
# "numeric" "numeric" "numeric" "numeric" "numeric" "numeric" "numeric" "numeric" 
#       Fe      Type 
# "numeric"  "factor"
```

When you use `apply()`, it will first coerce `Glass` into a matrix. A matrix, like a vector, can only hold one type of data. Now, your data frame has both numeric and factor, the resulting matrix will be character only. `skewness()` will have nothing to do in this case, as none of the columns is numeric (so you got `NULL`).

If you use `sapply()` or `lapply()`, things are different. These functions are designed to work with lists / data frames. You will get valid result for all numeric columns.

Whether to use `sapply()` or `lapply()` depends on what you want. `sapply()` returns a vector / matrix whenever it can, while `lapply()` returns a list (by default). I reckoned that `skewness()` only returns a scalar result, so recommended using `sapply()`, by which you end up with a vector. If you want a data frame, use `as.data.frame(lapply(Glass, skewness))` instead.

Comment: He could also do `apply(a[,1:9], 2, funNum)`, which would side-step the down-conversion by omitting the `factor` column.

Comment: Agreed. Unfortunately, both return a `matrix` and not a data.frame. `lapply` may be a better fit since it at least is closer to a `data.frame`, or a `data.frame`-specific function such as those provided by `plyr` or `dplyr`, but those weren't requested.

Answer (score 0):

What happens is `apply` coerces to a matrix and converts the numeric columns to character so your function returns NULL

Try

```
sapply(a,funNum)
```

This will loop over columns of `a` without coercing to matrix

Comment: It does not coerces when all my columns are of numeric type and returns correct result.

Comment: That's because it is coercing to a numeric matrix in the case where you have a DF with all numerics